# Insert line in each cell value in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I normally use R for data analysis, but I wanted to try excel for this problem. I have my data in Excel cells like below.

[image: cells]

I want to convert them in this format:

[image]

Please note I have thousands of cells, so doing alt+enter wouldn't work for me. I also tried replacing `(` with `\n(`, but that won't do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of tricks which you can try

**1. Formula way**

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",CHAR(10)&"(")`

`CHAR(10)` will add a new line character

**2. Find and Replace**

If this is one time activity then you can use Find and Replace dialog to achieve this

FIND : `(`

REPLACE : <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> followed by `(`

then press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

**3. Use VBA Macro**